# Anaconda cannot import libraries, but I am pretty sure they are installed

Tags: python, bash, macos, anaconda

How can I load in these packages I've just installed in Anaconda Python? I've installed Anaconda, and installed a package with the following commands in my mac terminal:

```
conda activate base
conda install pip
pip install datascience
pip install okpy
```

I can verify that these have been installed by running `conda list`, and both packages show up in that list.

I've searched around, and there appears to be some difficulty when I've had other versions of Python on my machine. I've tried to remove many of them, but when I type `which python` I get `/usr/bin/python`. Here's what my `.bash_profile` file looks like:

```
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/adityakamath/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/adityakamath/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/adityakamath/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/adityakamath/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

How can I change my settings so that, when I start up Jupyter Notebook using the Anaconda navigator, I will be able to import these libraries? The import statement I need to run is `from client.api.notebook import Notebook`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of python you should run in a virtual environment. You can create a virtual environment by typying

> conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda

where python=x.x is the version of python to use in your environment.

Then run

> activate yourenvname

.

After you activate your environment then type

> pip3 install client